# Android Java Multitasking operations on listview

Tags: java, android, multithreading

How to create dynamic threads for dynamic data? i have spinner item and depending on the spinner item selected, the listview shows whats in a database related to the spinner item. Here is what i want to do...

```
 _________________
|_________________|  <-spinner item     select an item
 _________________
|_________________|  <-listview         A thread for the spinner 
|_________________|                     item that runs through the
|_________________|                     list items
      _______   
     |_______|       <-toggle button    thread started by button
```

---

```
 _________________
|_________________|  <-spinner item     select a second item
 _________________
|_________________|  <-listview         First thread still running BTW. 
|_________________|                     if button clicked, a new thread
|_________________|                     for this spinner item created
      _______   
     |_______|       <-toggle button    thread started by button
```

---

```
 _________________
|_________________|  <-spinner item   Going back to the first spinner item,
 _________________                    the toggle button is on because its
|_________________|  <-listview       thread is still doing repetitive tasks 
|_________________|                    
|_________________|                    
      _______   
     |_______|       <-toggle button    stop thread by toggling off.
```

Here is my code

```
public class Sequencer extends play_Activity implements Runnable{
private String Task;

public Sequencer(String taskName){
    this.Task = taskName;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int switcher = 0;
    int limit = Tasks.size();//each listview item is a task in a list called Tasks

    while(switcher <= limit){
        //my repetitive tasks
    }
}

public void setTask(String taskName){
    this.Task = taskName;
}

public String getTask(){
    return Task;
}

}
```

---

```
public void ThreadMaster(){
    DB_Handler db = new DB_Handler(getContext());
    List<String> TaskList = db.getSpinnerSelectionsPossible();//returns a list
    int jobsize = TaskList.size();
    for(String job: TaskList) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Sequencer(job));
        for(int i=0; i<jobsize; i++){
            thread.setName(TaskList.get(i).toString());
            continue;
        }
        //thread.start();
    }
    Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    for (int i=0; i<=threadSet.size(); i++){
        Log.e(LOG, String.valueOf(threadSet.toArray()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask instead of Thread. Execute each AsyncTask in ListView's adapter.getView() & define a boolean: 'finished' for each task, then set it true on AsyncTask.onPostExecute() method to find out this task is finished or not.

When viewing the same list for the second time, check if tasks are finished before executing those tasks again and update the toggle button state based on finished state.